# How can I insert a unique value to the next empty index in a 2D array in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array, indexing

I want to have each index of the 2D array to have a unique value for each iteration but my problem is that whenever the user inputs the first value for the first index, it automatically overwrites the remaining empty indexes into the first index value...

[image: The result where it overwritten the remaining empty indexes]

```
   String[][] ProductAllData1 = new String[10][6]; // an array that may store 10 unique elements(each element has 6 values)
   String[] receivedPInputs = getPInputs(); // gets the values from a function that asks the user to input values
 
   for (int d = 0; d < ProductAllData1.length; d++){      
         ProductAllData1[d] = receivedPInputs;
     
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(ProductAllData1[d]));
        System.out.println("");
       
   }
```

Am I missing something to add or is my for loop not correct?

Your responses would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Obviously, If you are assigning same `receivedPInputs` to all your indexes, it will be the same

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the same value to all the indices.

Put the `getPInputs()` inside the loop!

```java
String[][] ProductAllData1 = new String[10][6];
String[] receivedPInputs;
for (int d = 0; d < ProductAllData1.length; d++) {
    receivedPInputs = getPInputs();
    ProductAllData1[d] = receivedPInputs;

    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(ProductAllData1[d]));
    System.out.println("");
}
```